# ¿Cuándo es que Thread.sleep(1000); en realidad no equivale a un segundo?

Tags: hilos

He programado un cronómetro que cada segundo incrementa una variable y la muestra en una caja de texto:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
acumulador++;
jTextField1.setText(acumulador);
```

Además se ejecutan otras tareas, pero tras una hora de ejecución he notado que hay un retraso de dos o tres segundos, y he reducido los 1000 ms a 990 para ajustarlo, pero pienso que al llevarlo a otras computadoras habrá diferencias entre ellas, sospecho que el procesamiento de todo el código conlleva un retraso adicional y por eso el retraso, mi pregunta es ¿qué posibles explicaciones hay para el retraso, de tal modo que 1000 ms realmente no equivalen a un segundo en la ejecución?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no no.. el delay es siempre de 1 segundo... el problema es que lo otro tambien toma tiempo, o sea que al llegar a esa linea para 1 segundo... pero todo el otro codigo, tarda tambien...

Answer (score 3):

para contestar tu pregunta:

> ¿Cuándo es que Thread.sleep(1000); en realidad no equivale a un segundo?

Si equivale a un segundo, pero lo que causa el retraso es algo conocido como "`drift`".

Cada vez que se ejecute el código, tu `Thread.sleep(1000);` no se ejecutara en el mismo milisegundo

(por ejemplo: tu primer incremento seria en el tiempo de 0.00 segundos, el segundo quizá seria 1.01s, luego 2.02s, 3.04s.... y así)

Para lograr el cronometro que quieres, seria mejor utilizar [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)